# Mutual dependency of polynomial expressions

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

Suppose you are given the values of $m$ polynomial expressions in $n$ variables.

That is we know that $P_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=a_1,P_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=a_2,...,P_m(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=a_m$ for some $a_1,a_2,...,a_m$.

The values of which polynomial expressions in $x_1,...,x_n$ are now uniquely determined?

For example if we know the value of $ab$ and $a+b$ all symmetric expressions in $a,b$ are now uniquely determined, but all other expressions are not.

Comment: Are you expecting something other than "Linear combinations of $P_i$"?

Comment: Linear combinations of $P_i$ is not the right answer. For example the value of the expression $P_1^2$ is uniquely determined and yet it is not a linear combination of $P_i$s.

Comment: Linear combinations of $P_i$ where the coefficients are $\mathbb{C} [P_1, P_2, \ldots P_m]$. It could be different if you don't work in an algebraically closed field, since for example $(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 0 $ tells us that the point is $(1,2)$ and hence all polynomials are uniquely determined.

Comment: Aha so just to make it clear $\mathbb{C} [P_1, P_2, \ldots P_m]$ is the set of all polynomials in the $P_1,P_2,...,P_m$ with complex coefficients?

In that case the way I see it that set of linear combinations equals to $\mathbb{C} [P_1, P_2, \ldots P_m]$. I would be very interested to know if these expressions are the only ones whose value is uniquely determined. It's clear that their value is determined but it's not clear to me that the value of no other expression is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$The term you are looking for is **seminormalization**. Specifically, let $S$ be the ring generated by $P_1$, $P_2$, …, $P_m$ and let $Q$ be another polynomial. Then $Q$ is in the seminormalization of $S$ if and only if, whenever we have $P_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = P_i(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ for all $i$, then we have $Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = Q(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$.

Throughout this answer, I assume your ground field is the complex numbers.

There is also another condition called "weak normality", which is slightly stricter than "seminormality" in characteristic $p$, but the same in characteristic zero; since I am assuming you are working over the complex numbers, I won't distinguish between them. [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3334) is a good survey on seminormality.

There is a beautiful though perhaps not very useful description of seminormalization due to Swan. Let $S$ be a subring of $\CC[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.  The seminormalization of $S$ is the smallest ring $S^{+}$ containing $S$ with the following property: If $Q^2$ and $Q^3$ are in $S$, then so is $Q$. This situation shows the basic example of a case where the seminormalization is more than just $S$: If $P_1=t^2$ and $P_2=t^3$, then $P_1$ and $P_2$ determine the value of $Q = t$.

---

Here are some more basic rings which might be good enough for your purposes.

**The ring generated by the $P_i$** Clearly, any polynomial in the $P_i$ has the property you seek. I'll write $S$ for the ring generated by the $P_i$. In the rest of this answer, I'll consider rings which are larger than $S$. All of these other rings are larger than the seminormalization; they have "too many" functions in them while $S$ has "too few".

**The algebraic closure of $S$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.** An element $Q$ of $\CC[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is **algebraic** over $S$ if and only if it obeys a nonzero polynomial relation 
$$A_d Q^d + A_{d-1} Q^{d-1} + \cdots + A_1 Q + A_0 =0$$
with the $A_i$ in $S$. Since the $A_i$ are in $S$, their values will be determined by the values of the $P_i$. As long as the $A_i$ are not all zero, we will then be able to restrict the values of $Q$ to a finite list of length $d$ by finding the roots of the above polynomial. Indeed, if we have chosen a polynomial of minimal degree, then there will generically be $d$ values for $Q$ once we fix the values of the $P_i$. This is the least you should ask for.

There is a very nice test for whether $Q$ is algebraic over the ring generated by the $P_i$: Let $K$ be the field $\mathrm{Frac} \CC[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Then $Q$ is algebraic over the ring generated by the $P_i$ if and only if $\nabla Q := (\partial Q/\partial x_1, \partial Q/\partial x_2, \dots, \partial Q/\partial X_n)$ is in the $K$ linear span of the vectors 
$\nabla P_1$, $\nabla P_2$, …., $\nabla P_m$.

**The intersection $\mathrm{Frac} S \cap \CC[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.** One might want the number $d$ above to be $1$, so that there will generically be one value of $Q$ once the values of the $P_1$, ..., $P_m$ are fixed. In other words, $Q$ is in this ring of we can find $A$ and $B$ in $S$ so that $AQ+B=0$.

**The integral closure of $S$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.** Recall above that there are at most $d$ values for $Q$ **unless** all of the $A_i$ are zero. We can insist that this doesn't happen by forcing one of them to be one. Specifically: An element $Q$ of $\CC[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is integral over $S$ if it obeys a polynomial relation
$$ Q^d + A_{d-1} Q^{d-1} + \cdots + A_1 Q + A_0 =0$$
with $A_{d-1}$, ..., $A_0$ in $S$. So the values of $Q$ are always given by the roots of a degree $d$ polynomial. That doesn't mean there are always $d$ values; the polynomial might have multiple roots. However, one can show the following nice property: If $Q$ is integral over the ring generated by the $P_i$, and $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ ranges over a region such that the values of the $P_i$ remain bounded, then the value of $Q$ remains bounded.

**The normalization of $S$** This is the intersection of the previous two examples. $Q$ is in the normalization of $S$ if **both** $Q$ satisfies a polynomial $$ Q^d + A_{d-1} Q^{d-1} + \cdots + A_1 Q + A_0 =0$$
with $A_{d-1}$, ..., $A_0$ in $S$ and $AQ+B=0$, with $A$ and $B$ in $S$. For example, if $(P_1, P_2)$ are $(t^2, t^3)$, then $t$ is in the normalization because we have both $t^2-P_1=0$ and $P_1 t - P_2=0$.

So, when $Q$ is in the normalization, there will generically be one value of $Q$ given the values of the $P_i$ and, if the values of the $P_i$ are small, then the values of $Q$ are small.

---

Here are some contrasting examples to distinguish these concepts.

Let $P_1 = t^2$ and consider $Q=t$. Then $Q^2 = P_1$, but $Q$ cannot be written as a ratio of polynomials in $P_1$. Given a value for $t^2$, there are at most $2$ values for $t$ and, if $t^2$ is bounded then so is $t$, but we generically cannot determine $t$ from $t^2$. So $t$ is in the integral closure of $S$, but it not in $\mathrm{Frac}(S)$.

Conversely, let $P_1 = x$, $P_2 = xy$ and $Q = y$. Then $Q = P_2/P_1$ so, generically, the values of $P_1$ and $P_2$ determine $Q$. However, if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are less than (say) $1$, we can deduce no bound for $Q$. This reflects that $y$ is not integral over $\CC[x,xy]$.

Finally, let's see why normalization isn't the same as seminormalization. Take $P_1 = t(t-1)$,  $P_2=t^2(t-1)$ and $Q = t$. Then $Q=P_2/P_1$, so $Q$ is in $\mathrm{Frac}(S)$, and $Q^2-Q = P_1$ so $Q$ is integral over $S$. So $Q$ is in the normalization of $S$. Indeed, for generic values of $t$, the value of $Q$ can be recovered from $(P_1, P_2)$ and, if $(P_1, P_2)$ are bounded then $t$ is bounded. However, when $t=0$ and when $t=1$, we have $(P_1,P_2)=(0,0)$. So $P_1$ and $P_2$ cannot distinguish the points $t=0$ and $t=1$, while $Q$ can, so $Q$ is not in the seminormalization of $S$.

Comment: Thank you for this nice and exhaustive reply. If I understand it correctly there is no nicer "characterization" of the seminormalization of a given ring than that of Swan?

Comment: Not that I know of. I see that Karl Schwede has a note on his webpage http://www.personal.psu.edu/users/k/e/kes32/Notes/ThesisSnippet2.pdf about how to compute seminormalizations.